# How can i query a bunch of newsletters stored in parse.com?

Tags: objective-c, pdf, parse-platform

I have an app which has a tableview consisting of month, date and year of newsletters like "september 16 2015" etc. When the user clicks on a specific row say september 16 2015 it should show the newsletter stored in pdf format in parse.com for that issue. Right now i can only get one pdf in a web view. How can i achieve this?

Here is my code for web view:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Newsletters"];
    PFObject *gameScore = [query getFirstObject];
    PFFile *file = [gameScore objectForKey:@"pdffiles"];
    NSString *schoolName = [file url];

    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:schoolName]]];
```

Comment: Tell us about what's stored in parse...

Comment: I have a class name "Newsletters" and a column name "pdf" I have a bunch of newsletter off issues stored in parse. My code only queries the first stored file from parse.

Comment: Sorry typo not off its pdf

Comment: Any clue? I'm breaking my head for a solution. How can I link a button from viewcontroller to another  view controller having a webview and based on user selection open that particular pdf file in webview?

Comment: So you already have all the newsletters for each date? Or the newsletters have a date column in parse?

Comment: I have created a date column for each newsletter in parse now. I have a button in viewcontroller. When user clicks a row in tableview it passes the label to view controller and when they click the view button they can actually see the pdf. How can I program the button such that it opens that particular newsletter depending on the label value?

Comment: Can you tell me how to pass the pdf file's url as string in tableview cells?